# How to fix "Syntax Error, Invalid Syntax" (No context or reason why) Elif Function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm constantly getting Syntax Errors on my elif line (arrows pointing towards the end of the "elif".

I'm trying to write a program that allows the user to input a 3D shape and then input some data to calculate its volume. However, I'm constantly getting Syntax Errors with arrows pointing towards the end of my "elif".

I'm using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter as my console.

```
# Allows the use of Pi
import math

# Where the user selects the 3D shape
shape = str(input("Enter a Shape you would like to find the volume of! : "))

# Where it takes the user to a shape calculator based on what shape the user inputted
if shape == ("Sphere"):
    def vsphere(r):
        volume = 4.0/3.0*math.pi*r**3
        return volume
# Where the user enters the data of the shape
    radius = float(input("Enter The Volume of Your Sphere! : "))

    print("The Volume of a Sphere with a Radius of ",str(radius)," is ",str(vsphere(radius)))

elif shape == ("Cylinder"):
    def vcylinder(n):
        volume = math.pi * r**2 * h
        return n

r = int(input("Enter the Radius! : "))
h = int(input("Enter the Height! : "))

print("The Volume of a Cylinder with a Radius of ",str(r)," and a Height of ",str(h)," is ",str(vcylinder(math.pi * r**2 * h)))

elif shape == ("Cone"):
    def vcone(n):
        volume = math.pi * r**2 * h * 1/3
        return n

r = int(input("Enter the Radius! : "))
h = int(input("Enter the Height! : "))

print("The Volume of a Cylinder with a Radius of ",str(r)," and a Height of ",str(h)," is ",str(vcone(math.pi * r**2 * h * 1/3)))

elif shape == ("Cube"):
    def vcube(a):
        volume = a**3
        return volume

a = int(input("Enter the Area! : "))

print("The Volume of a Cube with an Area of ",str(a)," is ",str(vcube(a)))

else:
    print("Sorry, that Shape isn't on our List")

    print("Sorry, that Shape isn't on our List")
```

It should allow the user to input a shape (like a cube), take them to the shape calculator (Enter the area of a cube) and then calculate the volume based on the data entered.

Instead, when I run the program it gives me this error message:

File "main.py", line 27
    elif shape == ("Cone"):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Check your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You are having an indentation error issue.

You have to indent

```
    r = int(input("Enter the Radius! : "))
    h = int(input("Enter the Height! : "))
```

If we do not indent them, it is viewed as you have exited the `if` block. Hence when we are encountering `elif` outside an `if` and we will get a syntax error.

```
# Allows the use of Pi
import math

# Where the user selects the 3D shape
shape = str(input("Enter a Shape you would like to find the volume of! : "))

# Where it takes the user to a shape calculator based on what shape the user inputted
if shape == ("Sphere"):
    def vsphere(r):
        volume = 4.0/3.0*math.pi*r**3
        return volume
# Where the user enters the data of the shape
    radius = float(input("Enter The Volume of Your Sphere! : "))

    print("The Volume of a Sphere with a Radius of ",str(radius)," is ",str(vsphere(radius)))

elif shape == ("Cylinder"):
    def vcylinder(n):
        volume = math.pi * r**2 * h
        return n

    r = int(input("Enter the Radius! : "))
    h = int(input("Enter the Height! : "))

    print("The Volume of a Cylinder with a Radius of ",str(r)," and a Height of ",str(h)," is ",str(vcylinder(math.pi * r**2 * h)))

elif shape == ("Cone"):
    def vcone(n):
        volume = math.pi * r**2 * h * 1/3
        return n

    r = int(input("Enter the Radius! : "))
    h = int(input("Enter the Height! : "))

    print("The Volume of a Cylinder with a Radius of ",str(r)," and a Height of ",str(h)," is ",str(vcone(math.pi * r**2 * h * 1/3)))

elif shape == ("Cube"):
    def vcube(a):
        volume = a**3
        return volume

    a = int(input("Enter the Area! : "))

    print("The Volume of a Cube with an Area of ",str(a)," is ",str(vcube(a)))

else:
    print("Sorry, that Shape isn't on our List")

    print("Sorry, that Shape isn't on our List")
```

Comment: Dude, I've been struggling with this bad boy for days, thanks man! :P

Answer (score 1):

You are messing with indentation.

> Your `elif`s must be in the same level of indentation

. The calcul of `Cylinder` has to be in `elif shape == ("Cylinder"):`.

```
elif shape == ("Cylinder"):
    def vcylinder(n):
        volume = math.pi * r**2 * h
        return n
# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv NEED INDENTATION vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
r = int(input("Enter the Radius! : "))
h = int(input("Enter the Height! : "))

print("The Volume of a Cylinder with a Radius of ",str(r)," and a Height of ",str(h)," is ",str(vcylinder(math.pi * r**2 * h)))
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ NEED INDENTATION ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
elif shape == ("Cone"):
    def vcone(n):
        volume = math.pi * r**2 * h * 1/3
        return n
```

ps : no need to use parenthesis when comparing 2 strings